# Problem with Yii2 PDO Statement Postgres Query

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have some problems/doubt with PDO statement and Yii2 query.
I've search and read some question here but i didn't find a solution.
So i have an array like this

```
 array (size=3)
      0 => string '12345' 
      1 => string '6789' 
      2 => string '101258'
```

From this array i create a string to insert in my IN condition for SQL query

```
//$split_var is the previous array
$var_query = implode( "','" , $split_var);
//'12345','6789','101258'  i obtained this string
```

So now I try to create a query like this way

```
$tupla = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("
                SELECT * FROM oln, opt WHERE opt_cod = oln_opt_cod AND oln_cod IN ( :var_query) order by oln_cod ASC
            ")
            ->bindValue(':var_query' ,$var_query);
        $result = $tupla->queryAll();
```

It doesn't give me any error but the resulted query isn't what I'm expected. In fact I'll get that query:

```
SELECT * FROM oln, opt WHERE opt_cod = oln_opt_cod AND oln_cod IN ( '01Y0BIAN'',''05C2LARG'',''0661NO00') order by oln_cod ASC
```

The problem is in the IN condition and I don't know Why it added another `'`.

I tried also this method but I don't know how to bind parameters in this way:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
         ->select('*')
         ->from('oln, opt')
         ->where('opt_cod = oln_opt_cod')  
         ->andwhere('in', 'oln_cod',[':oln_cod' => $var_query])
         ->addParams([':oln_cod' => $var_query])
        ->orderBy('oln_cod ASC')
        ->all();
```

Comment: It looks like the array values are already wrapped in single quotes and your implodeit wrapping them again in single quotes

Comment: If you can guarantee that the values will always be pre-wrapped in quotes, you could just do `$var_query = implode( "," , $split_var);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `'` is added because of escaping. Since `$var_query` is actually a string, it will be treated as single string value and any `'` will be escaped to prevent SQL injection. You're building your `IN` condition in wrong way, you should bind every ID in `IN` separately:

```
$tupla = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
        "SELECT * FROM oln, opt WHERE opt_cod = oln_opt_cod"
        . " AND oln_cod IN (:var_query1, :var_query2, :var_query3) order by oln_cod ASC"
    )
    ->bindValue(':var_query1', 12345)
    ->bindValue(':var_query2', 6789)
    ->bindValue(':var_query3', 101258);
```

It probably will be easier to use foreach to bind all params. It is also much simpler with Yii wrapper, which has nice shortcut for building `IN` conditions:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('*')
    ->from('oln, opt')
    ->where('opt_cod = oln_opt_cod')
    ->andwhere(['in', 'oln_cod', $split_var]) // $split_var is array of values
    ->orderBy('oln_cod ASC')
    ->all();
```

Comment: Thank you for responding me, using Yii wrapper with the array like in your example i'm open to Sql Injection?

Comment: No, Yii uses param binding and PDO under the hood, it just saves you binding every param manually.

Comment: I have tried your solution but still, it's not working for me can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72976023/6854117)?

Comment: I am using MSSQL which is not in my model so how can I pass the connection to `(new \yii\db\Query())`?